# How do I get a bucket by name in the .Net S3 SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I'm trying to find a method using the Amazon S3 SDK for .Net to get a bucket by its name. All I can find is ListAllBuckets(), but I really don't want to have to do that then try to find it from the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
public static S3Bucket GetS3Bucket(string bucket)
{
    try
    {
        AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID);
        return client.ListBuckets().Buckets.Where(b => b.BucketName == bucket).Single();
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
    {
        throw amazonS3Exception;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something just like this for my solution. I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: @Ryan It would be slightly better to use this:
return client.ListBuckets().Buckets.Single(b => b.BucketName == bucket);

No need to use unnecessary Where function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ListObjects()` method

```
using (AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(AWSKey, AWSSecretKey)) {

    object req = new Model.ListObjectsRequest { BucketName = "MyBucket" };
    object resp = client.ListObjects(req);

}
```

Comment: I've noticed most sample code does not use `using` when initializing the `AmazonS3Client`. Not even Amazon's own sample code. I wonder why.